# C++ 64 Bit machine , shows 32 Bit heap address

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I created a sample C++ program on a 64 Bit linux machine running on VMware Player over host machine as windows. The below is a class code.

```
        class operatorOverloadingTest{
            private:
                    int age;
                    char *name;
            public:
                    operatorOverloadingTest(int age){
                            this->age = age;
                            name = new char[10];
                            strncpy(name,"Indra",strlen("Indra"));
                    }   

                    void displayDetails(){
                            cout<<"My Name :"<<name<<endl;
                            cout <<"My age: "<<age<<endl;
                    }   
                    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const operatorOverloadingTest &myObj);
                    ~operatorOverloadingTest(){
                            delete name;
                            cout<<" \nDestructor getting called"<<endl;
                    }
    };

In my Main function, created object of class:
1. By using new operator.
2. Stack Object.

int main(){
    operatorOverloadingTest *oOT = new operatorOverloadingTest(10);
    operatorOverloadingTest oOT1(30);
```

I understand that, on 64-Bit machine, memory address are represented in 8 Bytes.

When I run the program using GDB, i see the below address:

```
p oOT
$1 = (operatorOverloadingTest *) 0x613c20
p &oOT
$2 = (operatorOverloadingTest **) 0x7fffffffe228
 &(oOT1.age)
$7 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe210
(gdb) p &(oOT->age)
$8 = (int *) 0x613c20
```

My question is, why does object allocated in heap shows a 32 bit address representation and the object on stack (oOT1) shows a 64 bit address representation though my operating System is 64 Bit? (Checked using uname -a).

Comment: because 0x613c20 = 0x0000000000613c20 - it truncates leading zeros

Comment: Apparently, the compiler or runtime just happened to locate heap memory in the lower 4GB of the 64-bit address space.

Comment: @Anty: And the reason it does that, is presumably because it's much easier to see that `0x02000000` is not `0x20000000` than it is to see that `0x0000000002000000` is not `0x0000000020000000`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Yes, non PIE x86-64 executables have their static code/data mapped in the low 2GiB of virtual address space, so static addresses are usable as 32-bit absolute immediates / displacements, whether zero or sign-extended to 64-bit.  This allows addressing modes like `[array + rdi*4]` for example.  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) re: PIE executables changing that, and various MacOS Q&As (it always maps outside the low 4GiB, perhaps to help detect pointer truncation.)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, why does object allocated in heap shows a 32 bit address representation and the object on stack (oOT1) shows a 64 bit address representation

When you look at `0x1234`, you know that the entity has *at least* 16 bits, but you can't tell whether it's 16-bit, a 32-bit, or a 64-bit entity, because GDB will not print leading zeros.

If you want to know how big some program entity is, try:

```
(gdb) print sizeof(oOT)
(gdb) print sizeof(&ooT)
```

Comment: GDB does not print the leading zero's. Is there any command to check the memory map of my binary when it is loaded in RAM. This way i could check the heap segment starting and ending address and confirm that they have leading zero's. sizeof() shows the memory required by the object , i wanted to know the memory representation in the system used to address the object

Comment: @IndraChatterjee You are probably looking for `(gdb) info proc map`